# How to swipe between fragments in Google Glass

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-glass, google-gdk

I googled this question but I didn't get an exact solution to it. I want to know how can I use swipe options in Google Glass. In android phones, fragments are working without doing anything more but in Google Glass I should write some codes. From [this site](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-swipe-view-tab-layout-example.html), I get a simple fragment activity. I want to do it for Google Glass with swipe. (Gesture Detector maybe a solution but I didn't apply correctly)
Please give me a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by swiping between fragments. But of course, whatever sort of swiping gestures worked on a normal android phone won't work on Glass - Glass doesn't have a touch screen. It's a touch SENSOR, so it doesn't detect where you tap (for our purposes), but rather how far, how quickly, and in which direction you slide or tap.

The only thing I can answer in this question is how to create a `GestureDetector`. This is how I do it in my projects:

```
public class EXAMPLE {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gestureDetector = createGestureDetector(this);

    }
    private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context) {
        GestureDetector gestureDetectorTemp = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
               return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
               return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float v, float v2) { 
             return false;
            }
        });
        return gestureDetectorTemp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector != null) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

That last part is very important. On any generic motion event, if the gestureDetector isn't null, you'll send the event through the gestureDetector for processing.

Keep in mind what the `return` statements mean. If you want to be the only one to handle a particular event, you should `return true;`. This means that you handled the event and other default methods won't be notified. Otherwise, `return false;`, to signify that other methods can be notified.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I did it at last with gesture dedector. The codes are very similer with your codes but I dont get any error with the google's provide [code](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch)